# Book about a girl who talks to a tree (or boulder) and finds golden door

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magical-creatures

I'm looking for an old fantasy book. A woman/girl moves into new house and odd things happen that actually the tree or boulder in backyard is responsible for. The girl and the tree form a bond/relationship. Something about a trap room in the house and a old shed/garage with secret, golden door. The front cover was very colorful...

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "old" about the date? Roughly when did you read/hear about the book? Do you know if it was new then or not?

Comment: I want to say 1970s or 1980s (but I'm not certain). I read parts of the book in 2010 and it was in a selection from an English teacher at the time.

Answer (score 2):

[Prospero's Children](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/116367.Prospero_s_Children) by Jan Siegel (2001) trilogy?

The blurb seems to match nicely;

> *It began ages past in fabled Atlantis, when a mad, power-hungry queen forged a key to a door never meant to be opened by mortal man--its
>   inception would hasten her own death and the extinction of her
>   vainglorious race. For millennia the key lay forgotten beneath the
>   waves, lost amid the ruins of what had been the most beautiful city on
>   Earth. But however jealously the sea hoards its secrets, sooner or
>   later it yields them up. Now, in present-day Yorkshire, that time has
>   come. And for young Fernanda Capel, life will never be the same again
>   . . .*

[image: Prospero's Children]

Comment: Could you provide some details or matched points which line u with the details in the question that make you think this is the correct story or book?